# Replace unicode key with enter key

Tags: javascript, unicode

we are developing webb app for scanner, and we have a lot of different buttons on keyboard (QWERTY, green button, red button,...). What are we trying to do is to use green button as enter key for submitting a form. We already know that the unicode of that button is 125 and for enter is 13. Is it possible to replace my unicode? Bellow is my code.

Regards!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayunicode(e){
    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if(unicode == 49){
    alert(unicode)
    }

}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text"  onkeydown="displayunicode(event); " />
</form>
```

Comment: what does it mind "replace my unicode"? may be e.preventdefault() ?

Comment: I wan't to use enter and unicode 125 as enter(unicode 9).

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
if(unicode == 49){
  $(document).trigger({ 
    type: 'keydown',
    keyCode: 13
 });
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a detailed explanation of your answer.

Comment: Although this may solve OP's problem, you don't give an explanation of the solution and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Because the point of SO is to explain the solution and not just solve the OP's problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer